# PHP (poor man's profiler) incorrect hrtime() difference

Tags: php, docker, profiling, microtime

I'm implementing so-called poor man's profiling in PHP and doing it pretty straightforward way as you would expect:

```php
$start = hrtime(true);

// API request is more than 1 second long
$response = $this->getClient($cfg)->request($method, $url, ['query' => $query]);

// Exec time calculated in milliseconds
$end = round((hrtime(true) - $start) / 1E+6, 3);

// Result: $end = 2.642
```

Calculated execution time is always around very minor values like few ms which is unbelievably untrue, bec. endpoint has strict timeout of 1s. [`hrtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php) before and after API request reports very minor difference whether API request itself is not that fast. [`microtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime) gives similar results. cURL in turn returns valid response time.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Interesting fact is that script total exec time seems to be valid, but profiling points like these are strangely small. What is my problem?

---

#### I'm using

- [`symfony/http-client: ^5.4`](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-client#v5.4.8)
- Docker `php:7.4-fpm` image with `nginx`
- `x64`

Comment: Looks like you're using Guzzle, maybe it's doing an async request? Try using the built-in [on_stats](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats) feature to collect timing?

Comment: @AlexHowansky indeed. I'm using `symfony/http-client` which is asynchronous. Is there any recommendation on how I can deal with it going with such profiling approach?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for such behavior as mentioned by *@AlexHowansky* in comments is indeed the HTTP client I'm using - [`symfony/http-client`](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-client#v5.4.8). I completely missed that point from very beginning.

As [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) state:

> Responses are always asynchronous, so that the call to the method returns immediately instead of waiting to receive the response.

> ... unassigned responses will fallback to synchronous requests.

I switched API client to bare cURL requests what took a bit more lines, but wasn't too tricky to do.

Comment: Doesn't `$response->getInfo()` already include the data you need?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have another place to try it out, so will try it and update my answer.